# Problem with Excel Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.Comments property. [C#]

Tags: c#, .net, excel, spreadsheet

I am doing some work with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.
But when I read the document about `Workbook.Comments` property on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.comments?view=excel-pia#microsoft-office-interop-excel-workbook-comments

this property seem quite stranger when the doc tell that `Workbook.Comments` return a `Excel.Comment` but actually `Workbook.Comments` return a string.

While`Worksheet.Comments` is return exactly a `Excel.Comment`.

whether excel has any reason for `Workbook.Comments` return a string instead return a `Excel.Comments` of Workbook. Or this is a mistake from MS?.

Anyone can explain it to me?
Thanks

[image]